# Acces Denied to path when adding Web Reference

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-reference

I'm working with VS 2010 and I have a winform application that when I'm trying to add ANY Web Reference it finds it but it doesn't let me click on the "Add Reference" button. The wsdl file is on my dektop so there is no reason for me to not have access to it. Any help would be appreciated. I read a lot of articles similar to this one but not quit the same.

[image: Add Web Reference]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS then you need to find out from the application pool for the website what is the identity it is running under (by default this is Application Pool Identity) and grant that the correct permissions.

EDIT: Try Add Service Reference and not Web Reference

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not using IIS like you can see the wsdl file is on my desktop.

Comment: I found a way around. You just need to put the whole path with the name of the file at the end of the url: ...WPR4SHP.wsdl and it would recognize it. Thanks for the help any ! I'll give you a plus for taking the time for answering my question